# QDirIterator and Windows Shortcuts

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

I'm trying to find the shortcuts on the user's desktop from a QT 5.1 application cross-compiled for Windows with MinGW 4.8.1.

My code snippet

```
QFileInfoList result;

QDir userDesktopDir = userDesktopDirectory();
if (userDesktopDir.exists())
{
    QDirIterator userDesktopIterator(userDesktopDir.absolutePath(),
        QStringList() << "*.lnk",
        QDir::Files | QDir::Hidden | QDir::System,
        QDirIterator::Subdirectories);

    while (userDesktopIterator.hasNext())
    {
        QFileInfo shortcut(userDesktopIterator.next());
        if (!result.contains(shortcut))
        {
            result.append(shortcut);
        }
    }
}
```

works fine when running in wine, but omits all shortcuts when run on Windows.

The result of `userDesktopDirectory()` corretly points to C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the `.lnk` files that are showing up on the desktop are actually in `C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop` and not a shared location like `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Desktop`? Explorer displays items from at (at least) these two locations on the desktop.

Comment: Actually you're half right ;)
I'm also checking `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Desktop` but I forgot `%PUBLIC%\Desktop`

Comment: Good sleuthing. You can post an answer to your own question, including all the hints in the comments so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine, but it has to be noted that Windows combines the files shown on the desktop from multiple locations, like

- `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`
- `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Desktop`
- `%PUBLIC%\Desktop`